# ¿Cómo miro si una variable está vacía en Bash? ¿Cómo miro si una función ha recibido algún argumento?

Tags: bash, condiciones

Me gustaría saber cómo comprobar en un if si una variable está vacía en bash.

Ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 ]; then
```

Aquí me gustaría saber si el usuario ha pasado algún argumento y en caso de no pasarlo que no se cumpla el if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ver si una variable está vacía, debes decir:

```
[ -z "$variable" ]
```

---

Ejemplos:

```
$ [ -z "" ] && echo "vacio" || echo "vale algo"
vacio
$ [ -z "dd" ] && echo "vacio" || echo "vale algo"
vale algo
```

---

Para validar si recibiste algún argumento en el script, deberías usar otra cosa: **`$#` te da el número de argumentos recibidos**:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No se pasó ningún argumento"
fi
```

Pues esta aproximación con `-z "$1"` podría funcionar...

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "el primer argumento está vacío, o no se dio"
else
    echo "recibí argumento"
fi
```

A menos que digas `./script.sh "" "otro argumento"`, en cuyo caso el primer argumento será vacío, pero existente.

Comment: if [ -z "$1" ]; then la he probado y no me funciona y $ [ -z "" ] && echo "vacio" || echo "vale algo" tampoco funciona. pero if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then si funciona